# $(window).height() returning wrong value

Tags: jquery, wordpress, window, height

I'm unable to get a correct value when running `$(window).height()` on [www.presenskonferens.se](http://www.presenskonferens.se). It's the same in all browsers.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// Screen height sections
$(function() {

    function screen_height() {
        $('.screen-height').css({'height': $(window).height() });
    }

    screen_height();
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", screen_height );
    $(window).resize( screen_height );

});
```

Here's what I've tried:

- Using the correct doctype declaration (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)
- Removing all content within the div in question
- Removing all content in the js file except the screen_height function
- Removing everything in the screen_height function except `$('.screen-height').css({'height': $(window).height() });`
- Doing a console.log for `$(window).height()` and getting 12191 in return

I'm stumped. As far as I can tell, the error occurred when the site was updated to WordPress 4.0, but it isn't using the version of jQuery bundled in WordPress. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `window.outerHeight` or `window.innerHeight` ?

Comment: In addition, you should move the googleanalytics-script into the HTML - currently your page starts with a script before the doctype-declaration and ends without closing body and html ( = </body></html> missing at the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the doctype isn't set correctly, jQuery treats `$(window).height()` the same as  `$(document).height()`.

You have used the right doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) but by adding your analytics code before it, you've rendered it invalid.

Move your analytics code into the head, just before the closing `</head>` tag and it should all work fine.

Edit: I've just noticed you've got two different analytics code blocks. Get rid of the one at the very top (on line 1).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The analytics code hade been added through a plugin that I wasn't aware the client had installed. Deactivating it solved the issue.